# When I click run, nothing happens

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm very new to Java and I was wondering why my code wasn't running.

[image]

Is there anything I need to do or I have missed out, every time  I click run the bar at the bottom is just infinitely saying "running...".

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Your program is asking for an integer before it prints anything. Are you entering one?

Comment: Ok, I tried your code and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is asking for a user input before logging anything, that's probably why you think it's not running.

Try to print something before like this:

```java
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
int i = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("You chose " + i);
```

*(Pseudo code)*